# Merge conflict - Git rebase master which is master

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

So I am still newish with git and have just discovered the `rebase` option to update a branch with `master`.

I ran:

```
git checkout mybranch
git rebase master
```

Now I have a few merge conflicts. Is this the same as fixing normal merge conflicts? I want to accept `masters` changes. I get something like

```
<<<<<<< 6tyuhjhgty54rtfghgftr
=======
    <bunch of code here>
>>>>>>> Updates from Company
```

Which is which?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace your changes with their changes as a whole for a file, then you can do a `git checkout --theirs -- path-of-file`

In your example above, the code above the ===='s is yours and the code below is the incoming code.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `git rebase master` from your branch, the first thing git is going to do is checkout the `master` branch.

This means that the changes made on `master` are `--ours` and the changes made on `mybranch` are `--theirs`.

Alwyn is correct in saying that from there, if you want to, you can call `git checkout --theirs/--ours -- path/of/file` depending on whether you want the changes from `mybranch` or `master`.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase/

Basically It follows ["standard procedures"](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/)

Answer (score 0):

in your master branch you need to use

```
git pull origin master
git checkout mybranch
git rebase -X ours master
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).